# Input String Was Not In Correct Format (Calculator)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Ok so I created a program that calculates kilowatts to cost and whenever I choose 2 out of 3 appliances I get this error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

This is the full code, I'm not sure where I went wrong. Please help?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private RunningTotal As Double




    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim kw As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtKW.Text)
        Dim hpd As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtHPD.Text)
        Dim kwpd As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtKWPH.Text)
        Dim gal As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtGallon.Text)
        Dim cpg As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtCostPerGal.Text)
        Dim result As Double = kw * hpd * kwpd * gal * cpg
        lblResults.Text = result.ToString("C")
        RunningTotal = RunningTotal + result
        lblRunning.Text = RunningTotal.ToString("C")


        kw = Convert.ToDouble(txtKW.Text)
        hpd = Convert.ToDouble(txtHPD.Text)
        kwpd = Convert.ToDouble(txtKWPH.Text)
        gal = Convert.ToDouble(txtGallon.Text)
        cpg = Convert.ToDouble(txtCostPerGal.Text)








    End Sub

    Private Sub QuitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem.Click
        MessageBox.Show("This program was made by BD")
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtKW_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtKW.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(txtKW.Text) = True Then
            If (txtKW.Text = "0123456789") Then
                lblResults.Text = DialogResult.ToString("c")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtHPD_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtHPD.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(txtHPD.Text) = True Then
            If (txtHPD.Text = "0123456789") Then
                lblResults.Text = DialogResult.ToString("c")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtKWPH_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtKWPH.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(txtKWPH.Text) = True Then
            If (txtKWPH.Text = "0123456789") Then
                lblResults.Text = DialogResult.ToString("c")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub HelpToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HelpToolStripMenuItem.Click
        MessageBox.Show("This program was designed to help you determine your cost of appliances, simply enter the amount of kilowatts your appliance uses, how many hours per day you use your appliance, and the cost per kilowatt hour then click calculate.")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim index As Integer = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
        If (index = 2) Then
            txtGallon.Visible = True
            txtCostPerGal.Visible = True

        Else
            txtGallon.Visible = False
            txtCostPerGal.Visible = False
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblGallons.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtGallon_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtGallon.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(txtGallon.Text) = True Then
            If (txtGallon.Text = "0123456789") Then
                lblResults.Text = DialogResult.ToString("c")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")

        End If

    End Sub



    Private Sub txtCostPerGal_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCostPerGal.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(txtCostPerGal.Text) = True Then
            If (txtCostPerGal.Text = "0123456789") Then
                lblResults.Text = DialogResult.ToString("c")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why it is tagged to `c#`, Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2886/handling-formatexception-when-converting-string-to-other-types

Comment: I tried and I'm still getting the same message, any chance you could show me an example of how it should look?

Comment: at which point , the you gets an error ?

Comment: Its when I choose index 0 or 1. If I choose index 2 which is the one that shows the visible text boxes I don't get the error. Also If I do index 2 first then I can add calculate index 0 or 1 but not straight in the beginning.

Comment: Put breakpoints in your code and step through until you find it.